# How to align UIAlertController action sheet title vertically in middle?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I can't find how to align UIAlertcontroller action sheet's title **vertically in middle**. Following is my code, any help?

Update.

With the tips provided below I did some digging and found that the title/message is pushed up if the list is long otherwise it remains in center if list is short. See other screenshot

[image: Action Sheet]

[image: Alert]

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    // paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = // Is this the one? How to get the value required?

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Select Sorting Option", attributes: [
        NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20),
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.darkGray
        ])
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "",  preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle”)
```

Comment: How do you expect to have the title vertically middle by using `paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left`? You should be using `NSTextAlignment.center`.

Comment: If you don’t like the way the UIAlertController view looks, make your own view and present it.

Comment: @nayem paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left is for horizontal alignment. My question is for vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is working fine for me.

```
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Demo Alert", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: "Select Sorting Option",
        attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black
        ]
    )

    alertView.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I did some digging and found that the title/message is pushed up if the list is long otherwise it remains in center if list is short. See other screenshot